# Angular routing Home component only works when i click

Tags: angular, authentication, routes, auth-guard

I m troubling a weird situation right now. I m trying to create a simple authentication application. It was perfectly ok until now.

In my app, I send login validation to backend which is created with Express. Then it confirms and send ok response to the frontend. Here is the problem. When i try to click home page after logged in, it shows the home page correctly:

https://prnt.sc/umn5tx

But when i try to locate my browser to 'http://localhost:4200/', it doesn't show the home component which is already set my homecomponent path to '' :

https://prnt.sc/umn7u5

It should show it because . So here is the codes:

App-Routing Module

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'register',
    component: RegisterComponent
  }
];
```

Auth Guard

```
canActivate(): boolean {
    if(this._cookieService.get('access_token')) {
      return this._authService.loggedIn();
    } else {
      this._router.navigate(['login']);
      return false;
    }
    
  }
```

and here is the Auth Service

```
 _registerURI = 'http://localhost:3000/auth/register';
  _loginURI = 'http://localhost:3000/auth/login';
  _token = 'http://localhost:3000/auth/VpW02cG0W2vGeGXs8DdLIq3dQ62qMd0';
  isIt: boolean = false;

  token = {};
  user = {
    name: ''
  };

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private _cookieService: CookieService) { }

  registerUser(user) {
    return this.http.post<any>(this._registerURI, user, {withCredentials: true});
  };

  loginUser(user) {
    return this.http.post<any>(this._loginURI, user, {withCredentials: true});
  };

  getToken() { // this is for the validation of token
    return this.http.post<any>(this._token, this.token, {responseType: 'json', withCredentials: true});
  }

  loggedIn(): boolean {
    this.getToken().subscribe(res => {
      if(res.success === true){
        this.isIt = true;
      }
    }, err => {
      if(err.status === 401){
      this.isIt = false;
      alert('You need to sign in.');
      }
      console.log(err);
    })

    return this.isIt;
  }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check if there is error message in console when you are manually entering `http://localhost:4200/` .

Comment: No, there isn't any error message